# How to know what address a program in Linux crashes at?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, centos

I have a program running in Linux and It's been mysteriously crashing. I already know one way to know where it crashes at is to use GDB. But I don't want to attach to it every time I restart it (do this a lot since I'm testing it). Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use `ulimit -c unlimited` to allow crashed programs to write core dumps.

After the program crashes, you'll find a core dump file, called `core`, or perhaps `core.<pid>` if your program is multithreaded.

You can load this into GDB to examine the state at the point of the crash with `gdb program core`.

Answer (score 4):

First do a `ulimit -c unlimited`, so the program will leave a core dump.
Then, when it crashes, invoke `gdb` with the core dump, to read the
state of the program at the moment of the crash.

Comment: Yes.  A typo on my part.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your OS to dump a core file any time a program crashes. You can then examine the core to determine the crash location.

Answer (score 2):

-> compile the code with gdb flags enabled.

gcc -o < binary name > -g < file.c > (assuming it is a c/c++ program)

-> run the executable withing gdb.
gdb < binary name >

after this there are ways to find the crash location:
1. stepwise execution. 
2. run the code, it crashes (as expected), type "where" within gdb (without quotes) it gives the backtrace. from that, you can find out the address.

here is a nice quick guide to gdb : http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/